# Can I increase memory allocation to my Google Apps Script function to fix a 502 server error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, urlfetch

From Google Apps Script, I am calling my Cloud Function via HTTPS request, which then calls the API, and forwards back the response.  I am doing this because the API requires a static IP address.  I am getting a successful Status:200 message from the external API back to Cloud Functions.  Then I am trying to forward the response back to GAS and get Status:502 in GAS.

I think Status:502 is a memory error?  This function works for smaller responses.

My Google Apps Script function:

```
function gas_function(){
   var token = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
   var params = {muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }  };
   var url = 'https://'+REGION+'-'+PROJECT_ID+'.cloudfunctions.net/'+RECEIVING_FUNCTION;
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
// I should be getting my 'Status:200' response from the Cloud Function with my data
// This works with small datasets, but with a large dataset I get
// Response Code = 502 Error: could not handle the request
   return response;
}
```

My Google Cloud Function:

```
exports.cloud_function = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => { 
  var url = 'https://externalapi.com/info/';
  var api_response  = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(api_response.data); // this works!  I have a response with ~12000 data records
  // Now I just need to send it back to Google Apps Script
  response.status(200).send(api_response.data);
});
```

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is bound by a 50MB limit on response size. Trying to fetch payloads beyond that size limit will result in a server error( [see Apps Script Quotas & Limitations for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) ). Consider pushing your data to an intermediary datastore (Firestore, BigQuery) or breaking the payload up into 50MB chunks so that Apps Script can handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` receives a response larger than the GAS limit (50MB), you will get a Status:502 response.

Solutions on API side:

- paginate your Cloud Function responses to make them smaller
- do the GAS operations directly from the Cloud Function

See comments for link to Quotas & Limitations - thanks